# How to increase performance using association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Hi can anyone tell me how can i increase performance if association returns large no. of records. for example in my app :-

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inventory_items
end

class InventoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor
end
```

i am trying to find the vendors of my restuarant as follow :-

```
current_restaurant.inventory_items.includes(:vendor).uniq
```

current_restaurant.inventory_items returns large no. of records which takes maximum time. so how can i reduce this time please help me.

Comment: can you show us the vendor model ?

Comment: my rails application is running on ruby-1.9.2-p290 now i want to upgrade it. do you have idea on which rails i should upgrade, rails 4 or rails 5?

Comment: I suggest you to accept an answer on this question and ask you to create another question rather than asking here in comments

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of solutions that you can use depending on how your application is configured and what it needs to do -

1. Only select the columns that you want, for example, if you are only looking for the IDs, you can use the `pluck` or `select` methods.
2. As Chetan suggested in his answer, you can also add scopes, and in addition to that also add indexes for the columns in the scope depending on what kind of columns they are.
3. If you are looking at calculated values, consider caching them on the Restaurant table.

Comment: my rails application is running on ruby-1.9.2-p290 now i want to upgrade it. do you have idea on which rails i should upgrade, rails 4 or rails 5?

Comment: its highly encouraged to upgrade to the latest stable release of Rails. As of now, it should be rails 5.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a scope to your model and add a condition for the records you wanna fetch. Like

```
scope :your_scope_name, -> { includes(:vendor).where(*some more conditions*) }
```

This will help query to not to go through all data

Comment: what about if current_restaurant.inventory_items returns thousands of records?

Comment: You want all records?

Comment: no i want only vendors. current_restaurant.inventory_items.map(&:vendor).uniq                                                becuase of current_restaurant.inventory_items this line it takes too much time coz it returns thousands of records.

Comment: @awsmsid if you want vendors, why not `Vendor.all` ?? is the `inventory_item -> vendor` association optional ?

Comment: Well map is the fastest

Comment: i just want all vendors of current_restaurant so i cant use Vendor.all, current_restaurant.vendors.uniq  helped me.

Comment: by the way Thanks :)

Comment: my rails application is running on ruby-1.9.2-p290 now i want to upgrade it. do you have idea on which rails i should upgrade, rails 4 or rails 5?

Comment: What's the current version?

Comment: 'rails', '3.0.3'

Answer (score 0):

Use pagination, loading all records is never recommended..

see [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) OR [kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari) gems

---

Update:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inventory_items
  has_many :vendors, through: :inventory_items
end
```

Then,

```
current_restaurant.vendors.uniq
```

Comment: farhan i cant use pagination. i have three tables i have to find only vendors of current_restaurant as explained above. associtaion between restaurant and inventory items returns thousands of records now tell me how to deal with it. at last i have to find vendors.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but pagination is commonly a view concern where we want to have a page-view of our data, OP's performance concern is apparently on the model level

Comment: @awsmsid do you need `inventory` too or just `vendors`?

Comment: i only need vendors

Comment: thanks Md. Farhan Memon :) i did not consider this. thanks a lot :)

Comment: your welcome :). and if the list of vendors is large too, I would still paginate it. Trust me, it helps in optimisation and performance improvement a lot.

Comment: bro pagination is already present at view level. this calculation is at model side :)

Comment: cool..then besides my answer, you should consider indexing and scoping too as mentioned by others.

Comment: my rails application is running on ruby-1.9.2-p290 now i want to upgrade it. do you have idea on which rails i should upgrade, rails 4 or rails 5?

Comment: I suggest you to accept an answer on this question and ask you to create another question rather than asking here in comments.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the tables and how they are indexed, one sub query might be faster than a huge join:

```
Vendor.where(id: current_restaurant.inventory_items.select(:vendor_id).distinct)
```

Comment: my rails application is running on ruby-1.9.2-p290 now i want to upgrade it. do you have idea on which rails i should upgrade, rails 4 or rails 5?

Comment: Rails 4.2 [has reached end-of-life](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html) already. Therefore I would suggest to upgrade (in steps) to Rails 5.1.

Comment: in steps means rails 3 to rails 4 and then rails 5?

Comment: Yes, but I even suggest to update in minor steps: 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 5.0, 5.1. It might sound like more work, but in fact minor steps are way easier. You will find any of blog articles about what to change in each step. If you try to update in one step to 5.1, you will probably get so many different errors at once and it might be unclear where they can from and what to change in the app.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion :)